# Improving performance by using XML fields - is it possible?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

For a personal project I'm trying, for reasons of performance and security, to add display information in a XML field on the main table.
In this case Orders and Orderlines.

The current setup is:

tblOrders has 1 Index: `Clustered on UID`

tblOrderItems has 1 Index: `Clustered on UID`

tblOrder.Orderlines (XML) has 2 indexes. a `primary and a secondary on PATH.`

Now I'm trying following 2 queries:

```
SELECT Ord.UID
    , Item.DomainName
    , Item.BasicInfo
    , Item.Base
    , Item.Period
FROM tblOrder Ord
INNER JOIN tblOrderItem Item
    ON Item.OrderID = Ord.UID
WHERE Item.DomainName = 'domainname.com'
```

and

```
SELECT 
    UID
    , c.value('(DomainName)[1]','nvarchar(150)') AS DomainName
    , c.value('(BasicInfo)[1]','nvarchar(150)') AS [Basic Info]
    , c.value('(Base)[1]','float') AS [Base Price]
    , c.value('(Period)[1]','smallint') AS Period
FROM tblOrder
CROSS APPLY tblOrder.OrderLines.nodes('/OrderItem/line') as t(c)
WHERE c.value('(DomainName)[1]','nvarchar(150)') = 'domainname.com'
```

First one has a average time of 4ms while the second has a average time of 38ms.
Both tests were done with the same data, which is not a lot since I'm trying to decide what data model to use.

My question at last: is it possible to rewite the xml / xml query to make that one more performant then the regular inner join?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all SQL Server is *relational database*.

The whole point of relational databases is [`normalization`](http://www.1keydata.com/database-normalization/).

**First Normal Form:**

> A database is in first normal form if it satisfies the following conditions:
>
> **Contains only atomic values**
>
> There are no repeating groups
>
> **An atomic value is a value that cannot be divided.**

Using XML column you insert non-atomic data. Then during retrieving data you need to parse it to get specific values. Parsing is almost always more expensive than simple `JOIN`. So the first approach is better.